# How to update and select in one SQL query

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have the following function that should update then retrieve a table row:

```
MyEntity setRemoteMyEntityGUIGByMyEntityGUID(long myEntityGUID, long remoteMyEntityGUID) {

    sqlite3 *db = myDb();

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    char *sql = "UPDATE ENTITY_TABLE "
                "SET  REMOTE_ENTITY_GUID = ? " \
                "WHERE ENTITY_GUID = ?; " \
                 "SELECT " \
                 "ENTITY_GUID, " \
                 "ENTITY_TYPE, " \
                 "COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED_DATE " \
                 "FROM ENTITY_TABLE WHERE " \
                 "ENTITY_GUID = ?";

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, remoteMyEntityGUID);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, myEntityGUID);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, myEntityGUID);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MyApp", "ERR : %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    MyEntity myEntity;

    if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {

        myEntityGUID = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
        char *myEntityType = strdup((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6));
        char *timeUpdated = strdup((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 9));

        myEntity._myEntityGUID = myEntityGUID;
        myEntity._myEntityType = myEntityType;
        myEntity._timeUpdated = timeUpdated;

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

    return myEntity;
}
```

It, however, only does one of the two: update or retrieve the table row:

```
char *sql = "UPDATE ENTITY_TABLE "
                "SET  REMOTE_ENTITY_GUID = ? " \
                "WHERE ENTITY_GUID = ?" ;
```

**OR**

```
char *sql = "SELECT " \
                 "ENTITY_GUID, " \
                 "ENTITY_TYPE, " \
                 "COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED_DATE " \
                 "FROM ENTITY_TABLE WHERE " \
                 "ENTITY_GUID = ?";
```

This will not work wholly, but the first *(update)* part will:

```
char *sql = "UPDATE ENTITY_TABLE "
                "SET  REMOTE_ENTITY_GUID = ? " \
                "WHERE ENTITY_GUID = ?; " \
                 "SELECT " \
                 "ENTITY_GUID, " \
                 "ENTITY_TYPE, " \
                 "COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED_DATE " \
                 "FROM ENTITY_TABLE WHERE " \
                 "ENTITY_GUID = ?";
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to work?

Comment: I don't know the C/C++ SQLite API at all, but I will comment that you _can't_ do a select and an update in the same statement.  It _is_ possible to do an update and select in the same _transaction_.

Comment: Than you for the reply @TimBiegeleisen. It seems possible at [TutorialsPoint, under UPDATE Operation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm)

Comment: Yeah, sqlite only has one query per prepared statement. If you notice, the examples in that tutorialspoint link don't use prepared statements. I don't think I've ever actually seen anything use `sqlite3_exec()`'s callback feature... wonder why whoever wrote that chose that route. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you can only use one SQL statement per prepared statement, you have to break it up into two parts:

- Prepare the update statement.
- Bind any needed parameters for it.
- Execute it with `sqlite3_step()` (it returns `SQLITE_DONE` to indicate success, or an error code).
- Deallocate the prepared statement with `sqlite3_finalize()`.
- Prepare the select statement.
- Bind any needed parameters for it.
- Execute it with `sqlite3_step()`.
- Since it looks like you only get one row back, if `sqlite3_step()` returned `SQLITE_ROW`, do whatever you need to do with the selected columns from that row.
- Deallocate the prepared statement.
- Include appropriate error checking and handling in all the above.

(You're already doing most of this; it just needs to be adapted for the two prepared statements)

You also want to make sure you don't use the statements if preparing them fails - in your current code you're binding parameters before even checking `sqlite3_prepare()`'s return value. I also suggest using `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` instead - the older `sqlite3_prepare()`, to quote [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), "is legacy and should be avoided."